# Adding attribute based on Function in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, attribute-table

I would like to create a new attribute based on another attribute using a formula in GRASS GIS.

I would like to do multiple `'if'` functions embedded example:

```
if attribute x = 1.2: 1e-6
if attribute x = 2: 5e-6
if attribute x = 3: 1e-5
```

there would be as many embedded if functions as different values in my vector table. I can do this in MS Access or Excel, but I would like to do this directly in GRASS GIS.

Answer (score 2):

If your GRASS database backend is sqlite (the default) then the parallel to `if...then...` is `CASE...WHEN...THEN...`. So the CASE statement would look something like (assuming you have a column `attrib`):

```
CASE attrib
WHEN 1.2 THEN 1e-6
WHEN 2 THEN 5e-6
END
```

and the full v.db.update in GRASS would be (assuming the vector is named "my_vect" and the new column is "new_attrib":

```
v.db.addcolumn map=my_vect column="new_attrib DOUBLE PRECISION"
db.execute sql="UPDATE my_vect SET new_attrib='CASE attrib WHEN 1.2 THEN 1e-6 WHEN 2 THEN 5e-6 END'"
```

But if there are many values in the attrib column, this will get very cumbersome. You might consider extracting all the values, preparing a text file of the new attrib values, then running the update in a loop:

```
v.db.select -c map=my_vect column="attrib" file=attribs.txt
v.db.addcolumn map=my_vect column="new_attrib DOUBLE PRECISION"
# Now, edit the attribs.txt file so that each line contains a pair of old_value new_value
# Then run v.db.update in a loop
while read old new; do
v.db.update map=my_vect column=new_attrib where="attrib=$old" value=$new
done < attribs.txt
```